# How to create a hierarchical dropdown control?

Tags: r, input, shiny, dropdown, hierarchy

I want the user to be able to select products based on an hierarchy filter in my shiny apps as follows:

[image]

How can I achieve this through a dropdown filter? The filter will have approximately 6800 products at the 6-digit code in the hierarchy.

Comment: When writing titles, please don’t just re-enumerate the question tags, but actually supply a concise description of your problem.

Comment: I have used the `shinytree` library for something similar in the past - running out the door so no time for a full answer I'm afraid but hopefully should start you in the right direction.

Comment: packages shinyTree, jsTreeR, or cascadeSelect

Comment: There is no proper example of using them. I wanted the hierarchy to be checkboxes. If there is any example as such please share with me.

Comment: [jsTreeR](https://github.com/stla/jsTreeR) is full of examples.

Comment: There is no example where it shows how it can be used as an input in R shiny. I can't use it as an input. If there is any example available on how to use it as an input please share with me.